# jquery-1.4.1.min.js is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

The code below works prefect in visual studio 2010 but doesnt work on visual studio 2008,
if there any others exception that i miss out? what else i should check for in order to know what am i missing?

Noted* i can only received alert(starting) but not alert(end1) and alert(end2)

newest edited comments - i found that my jquery file is not loaded correctly, i dont want to use url, can provide me local src? i got few project file inside a solution, my Script folder is inside one of my project file, so what should my local src look like?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Starting");

var data = {
    btnSaveDraft: "this is save draft button",
    btnSubmit: "this is button submit"       

}

function ShowTooltip() {
    var Tip = $("<div class='dinamictip'></div>");
    $("input").hover(function() {
        Tip.text('');
        var ToolTipID = $(this).attr('id');
        var height = $(this).height() + 10;
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        if (data[ToolTipID].split('<br\>').length - 1) {
            var temp = data[ToolTipID].split('<br\>').length - 1;
            height = temp * 10;
        } else {
            height = 10;
        }


        Tip.html(data[ToolTipID]);


        Tip.css('display', 'inline').css('position', 'absolute').css('background', 'lightyellow').css('border', '1px solid #cccccc').css('color', '#6c6c6c').css('left', offset.left).css('top', offset.top - height).css('border-radius', '15px')



        Tip.appendTo('body');


    },

            function() {
                Tip.remove();
            });

}



   $(function() {
    ShowTooltip();
    alert("End1");
});
alert("End2");
</script>
```

Comment: In what way does it "not work"

Comment: Use FireBug Console to check weather your script loaded or not..

Comment: i found that my jquery file is not loaded correctly, i dont want to use url, can provide me local src? i got few project file inside a solution, my Script folder is inside one of my project file, so what should my local src look like?

Answer (score 0):

Use FireBug Console to check weather your script loaded or not..

add this line..instead of your jquery js file

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0):

May be this is the error, try to call in `doc ready`:

```
$(function(){
   ShowTooltip();
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that your jQuery is loaded? Do you have any error in console?

Answer (score 0):

Try running it in `$(document).ready(function(){ }`.  Also, there is no need to chain multiple css() calls like that.  Try using the syntax of `css({prop1: 'value1', prop2: 'value2'})`